# Set foreground image on selector?

Tags: android, gridview, selector

I am using grid view. I have Drawable with right mark (white color) with transparent background icon. I want to use this icon in selector when some option selected. But the right mark icon is not visible. Because selector is used to set the background. Is there any way to do in foreground?

P.s: In grid view I am using colors only. No Drawables.

Comment: Do you mean [check mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark)?

Comment: Not check mark like selector